# How to configure Docker Enterprise for Windows Server 2016 to use a proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, windows-server-2016

I am trying to configure Docker Enterprise for Windows Server 2016 to use our organization's proxy.   I see all kinds of advice for configuring proxy settings for Docker client, and even for Docker server on Linux, but I can't seem to find anything on Docker Server for Windows.  Any advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK this is embarrassing, I found the answer a few minutes after posting this.  It turns out that the answer is to use system environment variables.

```
HTTP_PROXY bcpxy.nycnet:8080
HTTPS_PROXY bcpxy.nycnet:8080
```

This article explains it elegantly: https://dille.name/blog/2017/02/12/how-to-configure-a-proxy-for-docker-on-windows/